# ActionPerformed action

Tags: java, events, awt

My program asks the user how many courses he has completed. So, the users enters the number in a JTextField. My programs has to take the number entered in the JTextField to create an array of all the courses completed.

```
package gpa;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;``
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Windows extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static String number = "";
    private content NbtextField = new content();

    public Windows()
    {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("GPA Professionnal Calculator");
        this.setSize(450, 250);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.add(NbtextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        number = NbtextField.getNbtextField().getText();

    }

    private void test()
    {
        System.out.println (number);
    }

}
```

So, I tested if my program proprely takes the number that the user has typed. But my problem is that my program doesnt wait for the user to enter the number and continues to run! So, the rest of my code runs before the user enters the number of courses completed.
How can I fix that so my program waits for the user input before continuing juste like a r.readLine() would do

string test = r.readLine();

Comment: Your previous question was closed, and was the same as this, why do you re-post? You also accepted an answer, why reposting the same questionif you have an answer?

Comment: @Harlandraka No, its exactly the same question. I still haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: `private content NbtextField = new content();` - Use standard Java naming conventions. Class names start with an upper case character. Variable names do not start with an upper case character. This was also mentioned in your last posting. Until you learn these standard, I won't even attempt to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the rest of your program once the number has been run :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    number = NbtextField.getNbtextField().getText();
    executeRestOfProgram(number);
}
```

Comment: Extract the end of the main method (the part that should be run after the name has been entered) into a new method, and call this method from actionPerformed().

Comment: Yea, but the rest of my program is composed of plenty of methods in my main class. But my actionPerformed is in the windows object. How can I put the rest of my program in the actionPerformed

Comment: Okay and is it possible to take this actionPerformed and put in my main class?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't do that. It belongs to the Windows class. The main class should pass an object to the Window constructor, and the actionPerformed method should call a method on this object. It seems you're trying to use Swing but haven't really understood what objects and methods are. Start with the basics. Swing is a complex API, and not knowing how objects and methods work won't lead you anywhere.